# How to make search field larger for adding record in master detail relationship

Tags: master-detail, user-interface

we have a custom object called "Request".
This has a master detail relationship with the opportunity object (we call it a grant and it is a record type on the opportunity object).

When you create a Request you can associate it with multiple grants.
Our grants have long names and our team has quested me with finding out how when you are adding a Grant to a Request how you can make the search box larger.

Here is an image on adding a Grant to a Request.  We want the Search box to be wider so it shows more of the title of the Grant:

[image]

How does one do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're using a standard record creation screen, you'll have to update your page layout to change that width. It looks like you've got a two column layout right now, but you can change that to be 1-column the lookup with display full width.

[image: Section Properties for Page Layout]

If you only want that one field to be full width, you'll need to add a new section in your page layout for just that field. Hope this helps!